# #define statement with multiple elements separated by commas

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm looking at something like this:

```
#define foo(x)   \
    (((a > b) ?  \
      0 : 1),    \
     (c ? 2 : 3), \
     (d ? 4 : 5))
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this. Can someone help me out?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Comment: Well as it stands this will result in a few compilation errors if you attempt to use it, since only `x` is declared in the `#define` and you reference `a`,`b`,`c`, and `d`

Comment: Granted that it is extremely bad practice, this will compile fine so long as `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are valid variables in the scope where `foo(x)` is used.

Comment: but what are a,b,c and d?\

Comment: Sibrajas - they're just expressions that evaluate to boolean values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially the `\` ignores the newline as far as terminating the `#define` statement is concerned, so each time you write `foo(var)` in your code it will be replaced with

```
((((a > b) ?  
  0 : 1),    
 (c ? 2 : 3), 
 (d ? 4 : 5))
```

The comma operator doesn't do a whole lot, except the final "returned" value of a statement consisting of statements separated by comma operators is the right most value.

All of that being explained, this isn't really a terribly valid `#define` since you use `a`,`b`,`c`, and `d` in the `#define` and only reference `x` as a parameter

Comment: Thanks Dan. I just copied the overall structure. Didn't copy the exact code as it may violate company policies. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator evaluates all of its operands and returns the value of the last one. So, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` will be evaluated and the result of `f(x)` will be either 4 or 5, depending on whether `d` is non-zero.